# How can I make columns based on 'datediff'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to make two columns from below original table.
Name of two columns are 'Avg_term' and 'Max_term'.
Two cols concept is based on datediff.

1. First, I expect 'Max_term' column show that maximum datediff(maximum days term) between two consecutive date.
2. Second, I expect 'Avg_term' column show that average days of all 'datediff'

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Window functions are your friend here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to get the previous date/time and then aggregate:

```
select max(datediff(day, prev_datetime, datetime)) as max_diff,
       avg(datediff(day, prev_datetime, datetime)) as avg_diff
from (select t.*,
             lag(datetime) over (partition by id order by datetime) as prev_datetime
      from t
     ) t;
```

I wouldn't be surprised if you want this *per id*:

```
select id,
       max(datediff(day, prev_datetime, datetime)) as max_diff,
       avg(datediff(day, prev_datetime, datetime)) as avg_diff
from (select t.*,
             lag(datetime) over (partition by id order by datetime) as prev_datetime
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```